# What is 'Arcade Mode'?

Tags: gas-guzzlers

In [Gas Guzzlers: Combat Carnage](http://www.desura.com/games/gas-guzzlers-combat-carnage), there's an option toggle during profile creation for something called 'Arcade Mode'.  There are no tooltips or anything though, and I have no idea what it does.

What is Arcade Mode?

[image: Arcade Mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [When arcade mode is turned on, the car has the same grip regardless of the surface.](http://www.moddb.com/games/gas-guzzlers-combat-carnage/news/gas-guzzlers-combat-carnage-patch-12-released)

Comment: I looked in a bunch of places with no luck.  Didn't realize it was something added in the last patch or I would have thought to check the changelog.  Thanks!